# How to convert 2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00 to Unix time stamp using xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

This is the logic i am trying to use .Should i sub string 2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00 and get 2002-05-30T09:30:10 and 06:00 separate and subtract and use it in the below logic.If there is any easier way kindly let me know.
{code}

```
<tns:timestamp>
      <xsl:variable name="date" select="/Order/@OrderDate"/>
       <xsl:value-of select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + @date *xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
      </tns:timestamp>
```

Comment: What is the exact unix timestamp that should be produced from the dateTime `2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00`?

Comment: unix time stamp is the number of seconds from 1970 to this date .

Comment: I mean with the offset of 6 hours should it be `1022772610` or `1022751010` or ??

Comment: Yes we should include the 06:00 offset too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should subtract the offset in your calculation. If you do:

```
(xs:dateTime(@OrderDate) - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')
```

the result will be:

```
1022772610
```

If you [convert that unix time into human readable time](http://www.epochconverter.com/) you get the correct GMT and local time:

[image]

Here's an example ([see it working here](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpW))...

**XML Input**

```
<Order OrderDate="2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00"/>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Order">
    <Order unix-time="{(xs:dateTime(@OrderDate) - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) 
      div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Order unix-time="1022772610" OrderDate="2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00"/>
```

Comment: Thank you ,I will try and let you know.

Comment: Hey i am using <xsl:value-of select="(xsl:dateTime(/Order/@OrderDate) - xsl:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) div xsl:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
and i dont see any outout at all.Its giveing me blank.

Comment: What does the `Order` element look like? Is there a default namespace (`xmlns="something"`)?

Comment: Yes it has a namespace
<oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="Order" namespace="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation"/>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>

Comment: @NikhilPreeth - You should declare it in the stylesheet with a prefix and use that prefix in your xpath. Otherwise, you could use a `*` for the prefix: `<xsl:value-of select="(xsl:dateTime(/*:Order/@OrderDate) - xsl:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) div xsl:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>`

Comment: how come it was working before ,should i use it for only this conversion or my whole code?

Comment: @NikhilPreeth - I have no idea. If you update your question with an example of your XML and XSLT, I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you it worked .i did not declare xs as a namespace.Once i did it wokrd no need to add to the xpath.

Comment: @NikhilPreeth - Awesome. Good job getting it to work.

Comment: Halley I have one more question.I need to convert the unix timestamp i got into integer.Do you know any way
(xs:dateTime($body/Order/@OrderDate)-xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')
That is the xquery i am using.